# replacing the values of a matrix cells in a data frame based on the index and column values

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

[I have a data frame that looks as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHfZa.png)

I want to replace the values of every cell in the matrix (data frame) by 1 or zero based on the following conditions
if (the right three digits in the index == the left three digits in the column name)

The results will look like that

[the required solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHFcc.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code which you have tried?

Comment: I do not think I have a good approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be more efficient to compare values in a matrix space.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
mat = (np.tile(df.columns.str[:3].values, (df.shape[0],1)) 
       == np.tile(df.index.str[-3:].values[:,None], (1,df.shape[1])))
df = pd.DataFrame(mat.astype('int'), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

         AAABBB NNNTTT  OOOBBB  AAAYYY  LLLBBB
LLLAAA      1     0       0       1       0
AAABBB      0     0       0       0       0
AAAYYY      0     0       0       0       0
MMMOOO      0     0       1       0       0
TTTLLL      0     0       0       0       1
KKKNNN      0     1       0       0       0
```

**Explanation:**
The first is to extract characters from the column names and indices separately, and transform them into two 1d arrays. Then, use `np.tile` to repeat an array and expand it into a 6*5 matrix.

The first matrix for the column names:

```
print(np.tile(df.columns.str[:3].values, (df.shape[0],1))

array([['AAA', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'AAA', 'LLL'],
       ['AAA', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'AAA', 'LLL'],
       ['AAA', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'AAA', 'LLL'],
       ['AAA', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'AAA', 'LLL'],
       ['AAA', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'AAA', 'LLL'],
       ['AAA', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'AAA', 'LLL']], dtype=object)
```

The second matrix for the indices:

```
print(np.tile(df.index.str[-3:].values[:,None], (1,df.shape[1])))
array([['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA'],
       ['BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
       ['YYY', 'YYY', 'YYY', 'YYY', 'YYY'],
       ['OOO', 'OOO', 'OOO', 'OOO', 'OOO'],
       ['LLL', 'LLL', 'LLL', 'LLL', 'LLL'],
       ['NNN', 'NNN', 'NNN', 'NNN', 'NNN']], dtype=object)
```

Finally, use the conditional statement to compare two matrices.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.